# Generating a query body in code

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to generate the following query in code:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title1": "brown"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "title2": "fox"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "title3": "dog"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my java code built with `QueryBuilders`

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery(); 
boolQueryBuilder.must(matchQuery("title1", "brown")); 
boolQueryBuilder.must(matchQuery("title2", "fox")); 
boolQueryBuilder.must(matchQuery("title3", "dog")); SearchSourceBuilder 
searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder(); 
searchSourceBuilder.query(boolQueryBuilder);

String s = searchSourceBuilder.toString();
```

And I am not getting the same string... What I am getting is:

```
  {
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "match": {
          "title1": {
            "query": "brown",
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "match": {
          "title2": {
            "query": "fox",
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "match": {
          "title3": {
            "query": "dog",
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

}

What am I missing...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you are using `.must` so you'll have a must and not should.

Here is an example to achieve what you want to do

```java
MatchQueryBuilder match1 = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("title1", "brown");
MatchQueryBuilder match2 = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("title2", "fox");
MatchQueryBuilder match3 = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("title3", "dog");

BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
boolQueryBuilder.should(match1);
boolQueryBuilder.should(match2);
boolQueryBuilder.should(match3);

String queryString = boolQueryBuilder.toString();
```